# How can I match two columns of data by name?

Tags: openoffice-calc

I have two sets of data that look something like this:

```
Bill  | 7
Sam   | 13
Chuck | 9
```

and

```
Bill  | 6
Sam   | 3
Beth  | 6
```

and I want:

```
Beth | 0  | 6
Bill | 7  | 6
Chuck| 9  | 0
Sam  | 13 | 3
```

I don't even care if the data ends up looking like this:

```
Bill | 7  | Bill | 6
     |    | Beth | 6
Sam  | 13 | Sam  | 3
Chuck| 9  | Chuck| 0
```

I just would like to match up the names.

Answer (score 0):

Your desired outcome - I've never seen such an order in "real life practice".

To use the data, I would go with an operating system tool to combine the source files
(like: `copy file1 + file2 newfile.csv`; new file extension for easily recognizing by OOo Calc).

In CALC you can then sort / filter, to show a persons data together, or sum / calculate with it.

If you want standard operations, like `SUM` per person, check out the pivot table feature.

HTH

Comment: I figured that merging two lists of names with data and matching the names up would have been a problem that people see often.  I guess not.  Maybe I phrased it wrong?  Would matching the names as an index and putting the data into an array for each of the index be more of the right way to think about it?  I still don't know how to do that in calc.  I guess at least I can look into that.  If you have any insights let me know.  Thanks.

Comment: Maybe I misphrased: the demo output you gave did never occur to me.
 
I would go:
Step 1: merge all your sources into *one* file (as with `copy`); Name that with a `csv` extension

Step 2: open that `result.csv` with Calc
 
Step 3: now you can do whatever you want...
 
Use a filter to show only one person's data - "Standardfilter" to transfer (persistent?!) one person's data to another sheet, use the pivot to sum/average, ... whatever